# How to represent class like an Entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a real entity `Division` under database model (EF 4.0).

Also I have to use this class to represent a **self-referencing table**

```
public class DivisionHierarchy
{
   public Division Division { get; set; }

   public IEnumerable<DivisionHierarchy> Divisions { get; set; }
}
```

How I can "convert" `DivisionHierarchy` into Entity?

Thank you!

Comment: use the designer to create a table with a navigation property to it's self ?

Comment: Do u mean to open a EDMX file and create that table there?

Comment: That is how i would do it, or you can just create the table in the database with a self referencing foreign key and create the entity from the database, then all mapping will be in place as well. Maybe it's even better to use code first, but i have no experience with that.

Comment: I already have a database entity "Division" which is self-referencing table. But I need to create some extra entity which should encapsulate "Division" to get "DivisionHierarchy" collection which include all tree.

Comment: Ok i think you lost me.. however, you might want to rethink your normalization so that all foreign keys and tables are in place and then just generate everything back from the database. If that doesn't work then i'm afraid i'll be of little use. good luck !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a DivisionHierarchy Entity which has one to many relationship to Division (1 Division to many DivHierarchy) and also has a one to many relationship to itself.

This will generate code which allows you to do this:

```
DivisionHierarchy hierarchy;
Division d = hierarchy.Division;
foreach (DivisionHierarchy divisionHierarchy in hierarchy.DivisionHierarchies)
{
    Division child = divisionHierarchy.DivisionHierarchies;
}
```